# PHP - Select data from database geting first record and others by 3 minutes value

Tags: php, mysql, select

I just wanna know how to select data from specific user in database but just print data in a interval of 3 minutes.

For example:
THIS IS DATABSE:

```
ID ------ User----- Hour----- Minute
#1 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 00
#2 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 01
#3 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 02
#4 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 03
#5 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 04
#6 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 05
#7 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 06
#8 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 07
#9 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 08
#10 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 09
#11 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 10
```

THIS IS WHAT I WANNA SHOW

```
#1 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 00
#4 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 03
#7 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 06
#10 ------ USERA---- 09 ------ 09
...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: By "the first" you mean "the one with the earliest time"?

Comment: Yes, I wanna get in database the earliest recorded time, and after show this record by 3 and 3

Comment: Is this always going to start at 0, if the 9:00 record was missing, what would you expect to see?

Comment: No, It's start from any number... It's a car tracker and it's sending data to database each second of any hour, depends of car status (acc on, acc off, etc..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick solution may be to use the modula function..

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (table.Minute % 3) = 0`

If you want to start from the first instance of hour,minute and then get 3minutes from that, you may use this query:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((table.Minute - (SELECT Minute FROM table ORDER BY table.Minute,table.Hour ASC LIMIT 1)) % 3 ) = 0;`

Working demo can be found here: https://paiza.io/projects/4tlF_ZtwTSmSHFY_YKhtaw?language=mysql

Edit:
You may get better results by using `GROUP BY`

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((table.Minute - (SELECT table.Minute FROM table GROUP BY table.Minute,table.Hour ORDER BY table.Hour ASC LIMIT 1)) % 3 ) = 0;`

Comment: This get any value and select by 3 minutes, not working properly. I need to get the first one in database not any value

Comment: Are you wanting the first one in the database and every 3 minutes from that?

Comment: this has a flaw, imagine your startting time is `9:04`, so the next one would be `9:06` according to the SQL statement, but you actually want `9:07`, so it is three minutes **after** the first row.

Comment: Yes @Tobias that's what I'm attempting to gain clarification. The main OP states nothing about starting time. Working on a solution anyway as it's quite clear now that's what he's wanting.

Comment: I also wish he'd put more specific info into his question from the start :)

Comment: Looks promising now, i thought of something quite similar to your updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Tobias. @AMVVeiculos Can you confirm the updated solution is what you are looking for?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript this works... Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm glad we could help you out :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [MOD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod)

```
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        User,
        Hour,
        Minute
    FROM table 
    WHERE MOD( Minute, 3 ) = 0
    ORDER BY Hour ASC, Minute ASC;
```

Comment: A thing to note: OP wants to start with the earliest time, which might not be the first row in the result, so you should order the rows.

Comment: This get any value and select by 3 minutes, not working properly

Comment: @AMVVeiculos Updated the statement

Comment: Now that i think about it... i think this will fail if you pass into the next hour or there are records missing (e.g. not every three minutes).
Also take a look at waht i wrote to @IsThisJavascripts answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the data with the modulus (`%`) operator.

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if($row['Minute']%3 == 0){
        echo $row['user'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not really effective though. If the Database can handle it for you, why bother wasting Ram space by loading 3 times more results than you will use?

Comment: Yess, you are rignt. I was just answering the question : "just print data in a interval of 3 minutes.".  I do not know where the data comes from and if can modify the SELECT as he wants.